# Agda not eliminating clause in goal despite pattern matching on it

Tags: types, proof, agda, theorem-proving

I have a snippet of agda code of the following form:

```
Terminates :  → S → Set
Terminates c s = Σ[ n ∈ ℕ ] ( Is-just (proj₂ (smallStepEvalwithFuel n ( c , just s ))))

evalAssiProg : ∀ {i e} → S → (p : i := e) → Maybe S
evalAssiProg s (id ꞉= exp) with evalExp exp s
... | nothing = nothing -- Comp failed. i.e. ÷ by 0 error
... | just v = just (updateState id v s) -- Comp success

example : ∀ i v exp s → ( a : i := exp ) → evalExp exp s ≡ just v → Terminates ( ꞉ a ) s
example i v e s (.i ꞉= .e) p with evalExp e s
... | just x = 1 , {!!} --<----------------------! Problem here
```

I'm hoping that the details don't matter too much, basically `evalExp e s` has the form `evalExp : Exp → S → Maybe Val` i.e. it takes an expression, a state, and spits out the value unless a divide by zero error occurs for example. So it is a tedious but simple function.

*All I'm interested in is*: how can I pattern match on `evalExp e s` in `example`, and have agda **correctly** work out that the only possible case is `just x` but still if I look in the goal on the right hand side of the product I have that the goal is still waiting on the result of `evalExp e s`:

```
Goal: Any (λ _ → ⊤)
      (Mini-C.Evaluation.evalAssiProg dRep sRep s (i Mini-C.Lang._:=_.꞉= e)
       | evalExp e s)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
i    : Id
s    : S
e    : Exp
sRep : S-Representation dRep
p    : just x ≡ just v
v    : Val
x    : Val
dRep : D-Representation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below snippet models your problem accurately:

```
module _ where

open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Maybe.Relation.Unary.Any

variable
  A B : Set

Terminates : ∀ {A B : Set} → (A → Maybe B) → Set
Terminates f = Σ _ λ x → Is-just (f x)

example : ∀ (f : A → Maybe B) x y → f x ≡ just y → Terminates f
example f x y p = x , {!!}
```

Here, the type of the hole is `Is-just (f x)`, and we would like to use the proof `p` to solve it. The problem is that we can't just write `just tt` into the hole:

```
just _x_26 != f x of type Maybe B
when checking that the inferred type of an application
  Any (λ _ → ⊤) (just _x_26)
matches the expected type
  Is-just (f x)
```

Because `f x` doesn't reduce to `just _`, since we know nothing about `f` or `x`. But wait, we *do* know something about it -- in `p`. So we need to arrange for `p` to make a difference here:

```
example : ∀ (f : A → Maybe B) x y → f x ≡ just y → Terminates f
example f x y p = x , subst Is-just (sym p) (just tt)
```

Here, (after unification) we have `just tt : Is-just (just y)`, and we rewrite its type with the equality `sym p : just y ≡ f x`, to `subst _ _ (just tt) : Is-just (f x)` which is exactly our goal.